# Why InstallShield 2009 doesn't overwrite file

Tags: installshield

Good day!
I tried to update my installation from version 1.3 to 1.4, but no files were overwritten.
I checked my Basic MSI project and Files and Folders files- they have always override option.

If I install it on a clear machine- all files install well.
But if I install from 1.3 to 1.4 - it does not update.

I changed Upgrade option from "Install Setup then remove unneeded options" to "Completely uninstall old setup before installing new setup" but it never changed...

Please, help me fix this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems,that i use a lot of key file attributes at my install.
When i clear it to just one key file- it works well.